# How to use String variable to obtain specific list of items in collections by using Extention Select Method

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, extension-methods

I have an class like this

```
class Processing
{
public string Region { get; set; }
public Car _car {get;set;}
public double Kilometer { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have Created a list of Processing

```
List<Processing> process=new List<Processing>()
```

Then I fill the list with data.There is an Extention Select method as you know. I can use

```
var result=process.Select(a=>a.Region)
```

But I want to use lambda expression as dynamic.Like this

```
string property="Region"; 
var result=process.Select(a=>property)
```

Is there any way to get data of property in list by using string name of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use reflection for this

```
string property="Region"; 
var prop = typeof(Processing).GetProperty(property);
var result=process.Select(a=>prop.GetValue(a, null));
```

Comment: Dmytro, 
I have used code above. But result is not as I want. Region is stored name of city like {İstanbul,Ankara,İzmir}.But result return value {5,6,7} etc...

Comment: You missed the second argument of `GetValue` which should be passed in as `null`.

Comment: @AykarKr. if you use the correct code (which provides the second argument as `null`), you should have the correct result.

Comment: Oops, sorry, for .NET version 4.0 and below you really should send indexer value (null in this case) as a second parameter of GetValue method. I've fixed example

Comment: Dmytro , your last post is still giving same wrong.There is numbers on grid